# Ionic + Angular

Tags: angularjs-directive, ionic4, angular-ngmodel, ion-menu

Help please,

I tried to fix it without success. I'm using Ionic framework and Angular. I have a form which is opened when I click on a Sidemenu. So the problem is when I add a formControllerName on the input field it modified my design's form. I don't understand why these input can change my form. I imported everything in my module's page where I needed.

1. my form without formControlName
   [form_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSDqY.jpg)
2. my form with formControlName
   [Form_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okIrP.jpg)
   [Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfmSf.png)

Comment: Provide full code or any error

Comment: hi Ravi, there aren't any error I just wonder why the fact of using formControllerName on input ( see picture) changes my design.

Comment: Yes but without code no idea what is the exact issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.